# ajax call aborted auto

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Im having a very weird issue.

I have a normal ajax call that upload the avatar you choose from your pc up to the server..

this works sometimes, sometimes i can see in firebug under the Net that after some time loading, it gets "Aborted" and marked in red.

i even have a ajaxstart ajaxend loader icon and the icon keeps showing even when it gets aborted.

Why is this happening, and how can i prevent it from aborting? And maybe how can i make a "try again" if it got aborted?..why is it even aborted :S

Ive noticed it happening on bigger demension/size files? And on the file it request(fileupload.php) i do have a checker there, to callback an error if its bigger. But i think it does not even get to the file before it "lags" and stops..

**Update** confirmed: this occurs when i try to ajax send file with bigger size..

Comment: Your call is most likely timing out. What method are you using to send files? Can you post your `$.ajax()` call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you sending files through Ajax? Ajax does not support sending files.

If it is a connection timeout in jQuery console it will show in red color and the failure handler of the ajax request will be called.

You can handle any conditions you want there. To remove `timeout` issue you can add a attribute `timeout` to your ajax request. I think the default value is 30 seconds

```
$.ajax({
    url : "",
    data : {},
    success : function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
        if(textStatus == "timeout"){
            alert("timeout")
        }
    },
    timeout : 600000
});
```

Since you are using ajaxfileupload try this

```
$.ajaxFileUpload({
    .....,
    timeout: 60000,
    error: function (data, status, e)
    {
        if(status == "timeout"){
            alert("timeout")
        }else{
            alert(status)
        }
    }
})
```

And make sure that you does not have any max file upload size set in your server.

Comment: im using $.ajaxfileupload with url:'functions.php?action=upload', secureuri:false, fileElementId:'file', dataType: 'json',

Comment: if the timeout has exceeded can i make a alert that it has been aborted?

Comment: I've to see the ajaxfileupload command. It will have a failure handler, you can use it.

Comment: The `$.ajaxfileupload` has an error property, try to use it. In case of any error in the request this handler method will get called with the status as `timeout`. EX: `$.ajaxFileUpload({
 .....,
 error: function (data, status, e)
 {
  if(status == "timeout"){
   alert("timeout")
  }
 }
})`

Comment: @ArunPJohny i do not receive any alert on the timeout??

Comment: Did you keep the `if` condition(`if (status == 'timeout')`) in the error handler method, remove it and see. Make sure the server do not have any upload file size set

Answer (score 0):

It probably got aborted because the request timed out on the client side. Increase the timeout in jquery.

Comment: what is the default timeout and any suggestion on what the timeout should be?